# FILL_PARENT inside a ViewFlipper inside a Dialog with no title

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper

I'm trying to create a `ViewFlipper` where each child View has some minimum size (based on their contents) but each should fill the outer `ViewFlipper`. So I thought if I make the size of each child `FILL_PARENT`, it'll do exactly what I'd like.

However, it seems what happens is the size of each child is calculated individually, then the maximum is taken and that's what the size of the `ViewFlipper` is, but the layout of the children is not re-calculated to match this new size. The weird thing is, this seems to happen only if `FEATURE_NO_TITLE` is set.

Below is a demonstration of the problem. Child 0 is sized `FILL_PARENT x FILL_PARENT`, and child 1 is `100x100`, so the size of the `ViewFlipper` is correctly determined to be `100x100`. However, child 0 is not resized to be `100x100`; in fact, it has size `0x0` (as you can tell when running the app and seeing the red rectangle with no trace of green on it). However, if you remove the line

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

then it works as expected...
What's going on here?

The code:

```
package com.example.flipper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ViewFlipper flipper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        this.flipper = new ViewFlipper(this);
        flipper.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);

        {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00);
            flipper.addView (ll, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        }

        {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setBackgroundColor(0xff0000ff);
            flipper.addView (ll, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        }

        setContentView(flipper);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        flipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.flipper"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was able to solve this with a kludge: I wrapped the `ViewFlipper` in a `LinearLayout` and set that as the activity's view:

```
LinearLayout llOuter = new LinearLayout(this);
llOuter.addView(flipper, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

setContentView(llOuter);
```